# preg_replace remove every char from ! until a single space is found

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete specific words.

```
$data = str_replace( $wordsToRemove, '!', $data );
```

But this leaves certain chars off words. So for example if **test** is a word to remove, **testing** is now **!ing**, and **tests** becomes **!s**

So I'm trying to get rid of these likes this:

```
$data = preg_replace("/!anyAmountofCharsRemovedUntilSingleSpace /", ' ', $data);
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Why not only replace whole words using word boundaries?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#105924

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$words = 'Hello there this is some sample text';
$replaced =  preg_replace('/th.*? /','',$words);
echo $replaced;
?>
```

Outputs:

> Hello is some sample text

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$words = 'Hello there this is some sample text';
$chars = array(
    'the',
    'so',
    'sa'
);

for($i = 0; $i < count($chars); $i++)
    $words =  preg_replace('/'.$chars[$i].'.*? /','',$words);

echo $words;
?>
```

Outputs:

> Hello this is text

Comment: So I have to do that for loads of extra chars I can think of? I'm sure there must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the words, why you are replacing them with '!'?

You can simply write

```
$data = str_replace( $wordsToRemove, '', $data );
```

which will replace the words by null.

Comment: Read the second part of my post. This will still leave unnecessary chars like ing and s off the words that were deleted. I'm trying to get rid of these by identifying them until a space. I thought the ! would help.